# How to check if have specific content in list and perform task based on content found in list?

Tags: python

I want to check if posted variable have value = "whatis" or "how".
If have "whatis" perform one task
or if have value "how" perform a different task

```
s = ''.join(wordlist)
question = re.findall('whatis', s)[0]

q = ''.join(wordlist)
question1 = re.findall('how', s)[0]
check1 = "whatis"
check2 = "how"

if question == check1
    #perform taskA
if question1 == check2
    #perform taskA
```

It's working if am only checking "whatis", but
when am checking if have "whatis" or "how" its shows error `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: this has nothing to do with django, so I've removed the tag (and the list/array-list tag).

Comment: it can be any from input box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check if a string contains a word, then you can use

```
if "word" in my_string_variable:
    ...
```

I'm not sure what this is supposed to do:

```
wordlist = re.sub("[^\w]", " ", addsearch).split()
s = ''.join(wordlist)
```

it's not needed to check for a substring match. If you just want to remove all space characters, then:

```
x = addsearch.replace(' ', '')
```

but I don't think you need it, and can simply do:

```
def addsearch(request):
    search_content = request.POST.get('searchcontent')

    if 'how' in search_content :
        # perform taskA
    if 'whatis' in search_content:
        # perform taskB
```

note that I've named the variable differently from your function.

If `what` and `is` are two separate words, then you can either do:

```
if 'what is' in search_content:
```

or

```
if 'whatis' in search_content.replace(' ', ""):
```

if `what` and `is` are two words that can appear anywhere, not necessarily next to each other, then:

```
if 'what' in search_content and 'is' in search_content:
```

Comment: in the list "what" and "is" must be different index value and near by , so how to find it

Comment: then perhaps the `search_content = search_content.replace(' ', "")` has a purpose (removing spaces will make `"what is"` into `"whatis"`).

Comment: list may contain many words ..not just " what is" ..so I can't do it....but"" s = ''.join(wordlist)
    question = re.findall('whatis', s)[0]"" this code work but when am checking if have "how" its not working

Comment: Are you saying the list can contain many words such that "what" and "is" are not next to each other (if they're next to each other this will work regardless of how many other words there are)? Instead of me trying to guess what you want to do, how about you edit your question and add sample input..?

Comment: I've updated my answer with all the combinations I could imagine you'd be thinking of...

Comment: for an example test_list = ["what", "is", "your " , "name"]
another one   test_list = ["hello", "how", "are", "you" , "doing"]
depends on users input values in list can be contain "what is" or "how" .
"what" and  "is" should be index next to each other